# Accessing Amazon EC2 site

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am new to cloud hosting and that stuff. So I finally managed to upload a file to instance using the code below using Terminal on OS X (Mac)

```
scp -i key.pem index.html ec2-user@ec2-50-17-89-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/tmp/
```

After that when I accessed `ec2-user@ec2-50-17-89-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, the page was not loading, so I learned I should have added the HTTP port and then added the HTTP port in security groups. However my site still isn't loading. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: do you set up a webserver? like apache!

Comment: no , how can i do that ? sorry am noob

Comment: I would say what you are looking for is a webhosting service, which Amazon EC2 is not. But if you really want to stick with EC2 ... depending on which image you took, you need to figure out how to install a webserver first. If you're using Ubuntu ... login with SSH then `apt-get install apache2` then copy that index.html to /var/www/ (I think that's what the document root is set to)

Comment: i know , I got Dedicated Servers,, but would like to store files in amazon

Comment: Use S3 then. http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/02/host-your-static-website-on-amazon-s3.html

Comment: if you want to store files, why are you using [Elastic Cloud Computing (ec2)](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/), instead of the [Simple Storage Service (s3)](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/)?

Comment: yea i used s3 , I just want to explore EC2 ? please some one help where i am struck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Did scp work without error? Was the index.html copied to the server?
2. Use ssh, connect to the server and make sure it is under /tmp
3. Copy your file (index.html) to teh document root of the Apache server
4. Check it in the browser
5. What is the result? If it doesn't work, check the access.log of Apache server: what messages do you see there?

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of your instance?
"Amazon Linux AMI" ?
"Red Hat"?
"SUSE"?
"Ubuntu"?

ssh access with "ec2-user" works only for "Amazon Linux AMI". For the others you should configure ssh access as for usual Linux system, i.e. you should add the public key to .ssh/authorized_keys.

Comment: I use Linux instance

Answer (score 0):

So if you use different OS type, you might want to do following:

1. Drop the current instance
2. Create a new instance of type "Amazon Linux AMI"

Keep in mind, that it is based on Red Hat, not Ubuntu. That's why "apt-get" (answer of Igor Serko) will not work. You should use "yum install".

Comment: i installed apache succussfully

Comment: now hot to upload files

Comment: Apache has nothing to do with your problem with "scp". Which Linux of following have you installed: "Amazon Linux AMI" ? "Red Hat"? "SUSE"? "Ubuntu"?

Comment: Amazon linux ami